# Configuring an error page in tomcat for multiple web apps

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I have multiple webapps deployed on tomcat. I have configured error page in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` :

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

My requirement is to create only one `error.jsp` page that can be accessed by all the webapps. But when I create an `error.jsp` page and put it in `$CATALINA_BASE/error.jsp` location, my webapps are not able to access it when an exception occurs say ArithmeticException. It redirects to a blank page instead.

The only way I could access the error page is by creating an individual error page for each application and put it in respective `WEB_INF` folder. But I want only one `error.jsp` file that can be shared by multiple webapps. Is it possible?